# how generate javaDoc from a jaxb file

Tags: java, documentation, jaxb, javadoc, documentation-generation

i am working with Jaxb. and i would like to generate javaDoc files from these classes, is it the same way as i would do it to a regular java files?

Comment: @special0ne did you manage to resolve your problem? Share

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `xs:annotation` with `xs:documentation` and jaxb picks them up and makes them javadoc on the class.

Notes:

- when the xs:documentation tag was
  outside the xs:complexType tag, it
  didn't pick up (understandably)
- I'll assume the same can be done at the
  attribute / element level in the .xsd
  for fields of the class, but didn't try.
- the output is ugly if you try to put HTML tags
  in the documentation.  There's
  probably a way around that, but I
  didn't try that either.

```
    <xs:complexType name="TypeThatBecomesJavaClass">
      <xs:annotation>
       <xs:documentation>
           This becomes javadoc for TypeThatBecomesJavaClass
      </xs:documentation>
     </xs:annotation>
    ... etc ...
```

Answer (score 2):

A more direct approach (from the JAXB tutorial) which addresses the concerns above: http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_5_4-Adding-Documentation.html#Adding%20Documentation

Comment: Yeah, only requires like 9 lines for a single comment, yuk!

Comment: If the Schema is not authored by you and a large scheme this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have generated `.java` files from `.xsd` - yes, they are regular classes which you can modify, comment and document.

Comment: Egh... Generated files shouldn't be edited manually. Such edits will be lost after re-generation!